# Angular 2 : Required Validation is not showing

Tags: angular

HTML :

```
<input type="text" id="txtFName" formControlName="firstName" required/>
```

`<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" (click)="save()"/>`

component.ts :

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.regForm=this.formBuilder.group({
        firstName:['', Validators.required],
        lastName:['', Validators.required],
        eMail:['', Validators.required],
        DOB:['', Validators.required]
    })
}

    save():void
{
    console.log(this.regForm.value);
}
```

while clicking submit button, required validation is not arising.

Please let me know what is needed to be done

Comment: Cause you have nothing to show. I would recommend adding a color or something and disable the button till required is filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make the submit button disable if the form is invalid

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" (click)="save()" [disabled]="!form.valid"/> // form is the formGroup name
```

Or use an error msg

```
<input type="text" id="txtFName" formControlName="firstName" required/>
<div [hidden]="firstName.valid">Name Required</div>
```

Comment: I want to show the user that the particular field is required like that

Answer (score 2):

For the alert to the user :

```
<div *ngIf="regForm.hasError('firstName', ['required'])">Required</div>
```

For validation

```
save() {
  if (this.regForm.invalid) { /* error */ }
}
```